# Does the django's formset.is_valid() work?

Tags: django, validation, formset

I have such simple view:

```
import datetime
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, render_to_response
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from form_utils.forms import BetterForm

from fb_app import models as fb_model
from learn_forms import models as lf_model

class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    #pub_date = forms.DateField()


def formset(request):
    print request.POST
    ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm)  # [1]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST)
        print formset.is_valid()
        if formset.is_valid():
            # do something with the formset.cleaned_data
            pass
    else:
        formset = ArticleFormSet()
        print formset.is_valid()
    return render(request, 'formset.html', {
        'formset': formset,
    })
```

I click submit with empty *title field* and the formset validation says it's valid (i expect message about required value)
But if swap formset with the form like this:

```
ArticleFormSet = ArticleForm
```

at line marked by: "# [1]" form shows message 'This field is required' (which i expect)

html file:

```
<form method="post" action="/lf/formset">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ formset }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: *Where* does it fail? Exactly what error do you get? Note that the `is_valid()` call in the `else` clause will fail, because [unbound forms are not valid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#behavior-of-unbound-forms).

Comment: updated, i expect message about required title

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are calling the form inside templates. This is how it should look like:

```
<form method="post" action="/lf/formset">
    <table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.as_p }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

You can learn more about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template).